# Visual Studio Code project won't see newly created file and folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I opened vscode with administration privilage and ran this command '`dotnet new mvc -o myproject --framework net6.0`' and then created a folder and then a cs file insider that folder but can not reference that folder or cs file in like any class(like HomeController or any other class) at all. And I can not not build project because it gives error saying ' `The type or namespace name '******' does not exist in the namespace '*****'` '. So i tried;

1. Checked for permissions any folder and root folder. All were fine.
2. I restarted Omni but nothing changed.
3. I reload window but nothing changed.
4. I ran dotnet clean and then run dotnet build but nothing changed.
5. I ran dotnet restore but nothing changed.
6. I reinstalled vscode but nothing changed.
7. I reinstalled windows but nothing changed.

So how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Have you verified that the CS file is in fact included in your project?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed issue by adding a namespace in that cs file. After that vscode recognized this folder and file.